# How do I keep these messages from appearing after using phpmailer

Tags: php, forms, email, text, phpmailer

So I used phpmailer for my register page and I was able to send an email successfully problem is every after successful run these tons of text keeps appearing at the bottom of the page. I can't post the full text here since I believe it contains private information i think..

but every line of these messages starts with SERVER -> CLIENT (then ip, email and other random stuff)
any idea what it is and how do I keep it from showing?

Code used for phpmailer:

```
//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'lib/mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "---";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "---";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('----', 'First Last');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('', 'First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress("$email", "$firstname");
//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));
//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: ";
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}



                    }


                }
```

Comment: If you want us to comment on some unknown text you're going to have to find a way to post some of it.

Comment: Modify
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; to $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
As your debug is on the messages are showing.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the vendor folder then phpmailer then src and click on the SMTP.php file. Scroll down the file and find the const DEBUG_SERVER=2; Change this value to 0 from 2. It should work.